# Android error : org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: android, json, sockets, connection-timeout, android-json

I am working on JSON data parsing, I am new to this as i am doing JSON parsing for the first time. I tried an example from [This Link.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) It runs fine. But when i change the example code according to my need i got error. My changed code is as follows :

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "https://123.xxx.x.xxx/DEMO/login_data.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "Status";
private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "User Name";
private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "Admin password";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray sampleData = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userNamePass;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userNamePass = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.password))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PASSWORD, cost);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                sampleData = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_STATUS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < sampleData.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = sampleData.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    String password = c.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_USERNAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_PASSWORD, password);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    userNamePass.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, userNamePass,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_USERNAME, TAG_PASSWORD }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.password });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
}
```

**ServiceHandler.Java**

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
}
```

**SingleContactActivity.Java**

```
public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {

// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String password = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PASSWORD);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblPassword.setText(password);
}
}
```

**Error I am getting while running:**

```
02-24 17:34:25.190: W/System.err(14285): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /123.xxx.x.xxx:443 timed out
02-24 17:34:25.190: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
02-24 17:34:25.190: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
02-24 17:34:25.195: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-24 17:34:25.195: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-24 17:34:25.195: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
02-24 17:34:25.195: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-24 17:34:25.200: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-24 17:34:25.200: W/System.err(14285):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-24 17:34:25.200: W/System.err(14285):    at com.oi.jsonparsingdemo.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:59)
02-24 17:34:25.205: W/System.err(14285):    at com.oi.jsonparsingdemo.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:34)
02-24 17:34:25.210: W/System.err(14285):    at com.oi.jsonparsingdemo.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
02-24 17:34:25.210: W/System.err(14285):    at com.oi.jsonparsingdemo.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-24 17:34:25.215: W/System.err(14285):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-24 17:34:25.215: W/System.err(14285):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
02-24 17:34:25.215: W/System.err(14285):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-24 17:34:25.220: W/System.err(14285):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-24 17:34:25.220: W/System.err(14285):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-24 17:34:25.220: W/System.err(14285):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-24 17:34:25.220: D/Response:(14285): > null
02-24 17:34:25.220: E/ServiceHandler(14285): Couldn't get any data from the url
02-24 17:34:25.280: D/CLIPBOARD(14285): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
```

Where i am wrong or what steps should i follow not to acheve my task. Please give your valuable suggestions...

Comment: Please use below link code.
It's easy to understand. http://varunpatelandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/jsonparsing-demo.html

Comment: @Raghunandan : Yes it is working on browser. Its a local URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that your URL is right or not. I faced the same issue as my URL is http:// and i am accessing it as https://.

May be your URL is like :

```
// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://123.xxx.x.xxx/DEMO/login_data.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is most likely invalid. Change it to your appropriate URL.

```
private static String url = "https://123.xxx.x.xxx/DEMO/login_data.php";
```

That just doesn't look like any URL I've ever seen...

In the event that you masked it for SO, then make sure you get something by typing the same URL into a web browser, including the formatted strings. The best way to ensure this is to print the URL used immediately before using it, to ensure that nothing unusual has been added, and that the URL works exactly as intended.

As this is a local URL, it could be that your device isn't connected to the appropriate network. Try pinging the local URL from your phone (There's several utilities to try this, just look around).

Comment: Sorry but at best of my knowledge, Local URI does not work on phone.

Comment: It does work, if you are properly connected to the wifi network.

Comment: See my edit, basically you need to make sure the device can talk to your server (IE, on the same network, wifi). If the ping test fails, then try talking about it on the Android stack exchange.